# Homegrown consumption of web services

Tags: .net, web-services

I've been writing a few web services for a `.net` app, now I'm ready to consume them. I've seen numerous examples where there is homegrown code for consuming the service as opposed to using the auto generated methods that Visual Studio creates when adding the web reference.

Is there some advantages to this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, what you're doing is fine. Don't let those people confuse you.

If you've written the web services with .net then the reference proxies generated by .net are going to be quite suitable. The situation you describe (where you are both producer and consumer) is the ideal situation.

If you need to connect to a web services that is *unknown* at compile time, then you would want a more dynamic approach, where you deduce the 'shape' of the web service.

But start by using the auto generated proxy class, and don't worry about it until you hit a limitation. And when you do -- come back to stack overflow ;-)

Comment: Just watch out if you're planning on using SSL. The proxies that are generated automatically won't allow you to change the encryption method on the service. For example, on an Oracle/Java web service I had to consume recently, I needed to build my proxy manually so that I could specify the ServicePointManager SecurityProtocol as SSL3. ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;